# Airflow DAG Task Dependency in a Loop

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a DAG that needs to recompile this customer lists in various brands.   The script is called with two arguments brand and listtype.

I need the brands to run concurrently, but the list types to be dependent on the preceding list type, but I can't figure out how to do that in a loop.  Can ya'll help me out?

```
BrandsToRun = ['A', 'B', 'C']
ListTypes = ['1', '2', '3']

# Defining the DAG
################################################################################
with DAG(
        'MusterMaster',
        default_args = default_args,
        description = 'x',        
        # schedule_interval = None
        schedule_interval = '30 4 * * *',
        catchup = False
        ) as MusterMaster:

        for Brand in BrandsToRun:
            for ListType in ListTypes:

                ListLoad = BashOperator(
                                        task_id='Load_'+str(Brand)+'_'+str(ListType),
                                        bash_command = """python3 '/usr/local/bin/MusterMaster.py' {0} {1}""".format(Brand[0], ListType[0]),
                                        pool='logs'
                                        )

ListLoad
```

I want the tasks to have dependency structure like this, but I can't figure it out.   Brand should run concurrently, but ListTypes should be dependent on the preceding ListType.

Muster A 1 >> Muster A 2 >> Muster A 3

Muster B 1 >> Muster B 2 >> Muster B 3

Muster C 1 >> Muster C 2 >> Muster C 3

How can I best accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
    for Brand in BrandsToRun:
        list = []
        for ListType in ListTypes:
            list.append(BashOperator(
                task_id='Load_'+str(Brand)+'_'+str(ListType),
                bash_command = """python3 '/usr/local/bin/MusterMaster.py' {0} {1}""".format(Brand[0], ListType[0]),
                pool='logs'))
            if len(list) > 1:
                list[-2] >> list[-1]
```

Which will give you:

[image]