# Sequentially-executed dynamic tasks in Airflow

Tags: airflow

Airflow's dynamic task generation feature seems to mainly support generation of parallel tasks. Is dynamic generation of tasks that are executed in series also possible?

Specifically, I would like to do the following: A task (call it task_1) will create a list of variable length (the length will be determined at runtime). Then, for each member of this list, a PythonOperator and a PythonSensor will be generated and connected in series.

For example, the control flow would look something like this:

```
task_1 >> dynamic_operator_1 >> dynamic_sensor_1 >> ... >> dynamic_operator_n >> dynamic_sensor_n
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Airflow DAG Task Dependency in a Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64847484/airflow-dag-task-dependency-in-a-loop)

Comment: That seems similar to what I'm looking for. One thing that's missing is that I need to somehow retrieve the list from task_1 and iterate over it to create the dynamic operators and sensors. Do you know how I can retrieve the list while not inside of a task?

Comment: @bp94 unfortunately that solution wont work since you cant get the output of the list from outside a task.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to put the operator/sensor in a separate dag and parametrize that dag, then you could define a custom operator to trigger sequential runs of that separate dag:

```
# stdlib
import uuid

# third party
from airflow.models.baseoperator import BaseOperator
from airflow.operators.dagrun_operator import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from airflow.utils.operator_helpers import determine_kwargs


class SequentialDagRunOperator(BaseOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
        self,
        python_callable,
        *args,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.python_callable = python_callable

    def execute(self, context):
        op_kwargs = determine_kwargs(self.python_callable, {}, context)
        for kwargs in self.python_callable(**op_kwargs):
            self.log.info("Triggering DagRun: %s", kwargs)
            if "task_id" not in kwargs:
                kwargs["task_id"] = f"task__{uuid.uuid4()}"
            trigger_dag_op = TriggerDagRunOperator(**kwargs, wait_for_completion=True)
            trigger_dag_op.execute(context)
```

The `python_callable` in this case is a function that should return a sequence of dicts which will be passed into the `TriggerDagRunOperator`. `python_callable` can take the standard set of args that are available at run-time (e.g. `dag_run`, `ti`).

Usage might look something like this:

```
# stdlib
import datetime
import random

# third party
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models.param import Param
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.python import PythonSensor

# first party
from utils.sequentialdagrun import SequentialDagRunOperator

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1),
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 2,
    "retry_delay": datetime.timedelta(minutes=1),
}


op_sensor_dag = DAG(
    "op_sensor_dag",
    schedule_interval=None,
    tags=["sequential-demo"],
    params={
        "name": Param("foo"),
        "chance": Param(0.9),
    },
    default_args=default_args,
    render_template_as_native_obj=True
)

with op_sensor_dag:
    op = PythonOperator(
        task_id="op",
        python_callable=lambda dag_run: (
            print(f"Hello {dag_run.conf['name']}!"),
        ),
    )
    sensor = PythonSensor(
        task_id="sensor",
        python_callable=lambda dag_run: random.random() < dag_run.conf['chance'],
    )
    op >> sensor


sequential_dag = DAG(
    "sequential_dag",
    schedule_interval=None,
    tags=["sequential-demo"],
    default_args=default_args,
)

with sequential_dag:
    confs = PythonOperator(
        task_id="confs",
        python_callable=lambda: [
            {
                "name": "foo",
                "chance": 0.9,
            },
            {
                "name": "bar",
                "chance": 0.75,
            }
        ],
    )
    dag_runs = SequentialDagRunOperator(
        task_id="dag_runs",
        python_callable=lambda ti: [
            {
                "trigger_dag_id": op_sensor_dag.dag_id,
                "conf": conf,
            }
            for conf in ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=confs.task_id)
        ]
    )
    confs >> dag_runs
```